# How can I take a photo and save in Android Q?

Tags: android, photo, android-10.0

NEW EDIT:

I'm developing an android application and want to support android Q. When my app runs in target API(<= 28), everything works normally. But in android Q, when i take a photo and try to save it, something strange happens.

When I take the first photo, I can find it in my custom photo picker.
But I can't find the other photos taken after the first one.

But I can find all the photos by using adb in terminal.
Anyone has some suggestions?

I take photo like this:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
mCameraFilePath = MediaDataManager.getInstance().getFilePath(MediaDataManager.IMAGE, fileName);
// this function returns the img file path, like /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package-name>/files/Pictures/1556592144304.png
mCameraPicUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", new File(mCameraFilePath));
cameraIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCameraPicUri);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

and save photo:

```
try {
    File file = new File(=getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), fileName + ".png");
    if (file.exists()) {
         file.delete();
         file.createNewFile();
    }
     InputStream inputStream = =getContentResolver().openInputStream(mCameraPicUri);
     FileOutputStream out = null;
     try {
         out = new FileOutputStream(file);
         if (inputStream != null) {
               copy(inputStream, out);
               inputStream.close();
         }

         if (out != null) {
             out.close();
         }
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
}

Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, mCameraPicUri);
sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

Here is the copy() method:

```
private static final int EOF = -1;
private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;
private static long copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
     long count = 0;
     int n;
     byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
     while (EOF != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
         output.write(buffer, 0, n);
         count += n;
     }
     return count;
}
```

SOLUTION:
I should create the uri like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
mCameraPicUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Comment: How are you saving the photo...?

Comment: Related: https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/scoped-storage

Comment: @Morrison Chang Thanks for your advice, I will try!

Comment: I have edit the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SOLUTION: I should create the uri like this:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
mCameraPicUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```